# What this error means that I got after my git commit?

Tags: github

[image: github commit error]I get this error in github repository -

```
 err:  * branch            test       -> FETCH_HEAD
 err:    40fdfc2..21255ee  test       -> origin/test
 out: Updating 40fdfc2..21255ee
```

Comment: @plalx i got that error under that red cross in given picture......what that means

Comment: It cannot deploy. But that has nothing to with Git, but with your "SSH and deploy NextJS app" "task/job" (?)